# Forcing portrait mode makes Flutter app not responsive

Tags: flutter, dart, landscape-portrait

I was trying to force portrait mode in my flutter app.

For that, I found a piece of code around StackOverflow that I tried to use:

in **main.dart:**

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitDown])
        .then((_) => runApp(MyApp()),
    );
```

This resulted on the app becoming totally not responsive, i.e, no button taps, no response when clicking on Tab to change tab, etc.

I verified that the code above caused the problem since, once removed, the app works as normal.

Any better option or suggestion for that.

Comment: when you are calling above code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but solved by this, I hope it can help you,

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then(
    (_) => runApp(MyApp()),
  );
}
```

Comment: looks like it is not changing anything, but thanks for answering!